# can i use select where in(x,y,z)?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I'm a mysql beginner these days, i appreciate for your advise.

I got a problem my sql query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TB_AUTO_BAN(MEMO, REG_DATE, USER_ID, NAME, PHONE_NUM)
(
    SELECT 'test' AS MEMO, NOW() AS REG_DATE, a.USER_ID, a.NAME, a.CONTACT_NUM
    FROM TB_CONTACT AS a,TB_CONTACT_GROUP AS b 
    WHERE b.USER_ID = 'spark@naver.com'
    AND b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = IN(12800,12801) 
    AND a.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ
```

Bold text part is the problem, how should I modify it??

Comment: Maybe delete that line

Comment: what are trying to do ?

Comment: i wanna use IN(12800,12801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks ok, except for the `= in`.  Only `in` is needed.

I would write the query as:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TB_AUTO_BAN(MEMO, REG_DATE, USER_ID, NAME, PHONE_NUM)
    SELECT 'test' AS MEMO, NOW() AS REG_DATE, c.USER_ID, c.NAME, c.CONTACT_NUM
FROM TB_CONTACT AS c JOIN
     TB_CONTACT_GROUP AS cg
     ON c.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = cg.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ 
WHERE cg.USER_ID= 'spark@naver.com' AND
      cg.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ IN (12800, 12801) ;
```

In addition to fixing the condition, this changes the table aliases to be abbreviations rather than arbitrary letters.  It also uses standard `join` syntax instead of implicit joins with the condition buried in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

the equality sign "=" is superfluous. just delete it, and leave: b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ IN (12800,12801)